# 7-Zip, called from Powershell, cannot find one or more of the files to be archived

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I have a PowerShell (v1.0 on Windows 7) script that compares the 7-Zip archive timestamp with the source file timestamps and re-creates the archive if any of the source files are newer. The sequence that logs what the script is doing (if it needs to re-create the archive) is:

```
$logFile = "$env:temp\$zipFile.log"      # the backup log file
write-host "  Compressing ${newest}${otherDocDirList}"
write-host "  The log file is $logFile."

del $zipFile -erroraction:silentlycontinue
echo "  $(pwd)"
echo "  C:\progra~1\7-zip\7z.exe a $zipFile ${newest} ${otherDocDirs}"
C:\progra~1\7-zip\7z.exe a $zipFile ${newest} ${otherDocDirs} | set-content $logFile -encoding ascii
```

In some cases, this works file, specifically,

```
Compressing UserGuide_2303.docm, Graphics, and gettoolbar.
The log file is C:\Users\jim\AppData\Local\Temp\ST_SUG.7z.log.
C:\users\jim\desktop\ST\userguide\working
C:\progra~1\7-zip\7z.exe a ST_SUG.7z UserGuide_2303.docm Graphics gettoolbar
```

and

```
Compressing AdminGuide_0300.docm and Graphics.
The log file is C:\Users\jim\AppData\Local\Temp\ST_AUG.7z.log.
C:\users\jim\desktop\ST\adminguide\working
C:\progra~1\7-zip\7z.exe a ST_AUG.7z AdminGuide_0300.docm Graphics
```

but I get an error "SystemOverview_TrngMan_0103.pptx SystemOverview_TrngMan_0103.docm:  WARNING: The system cannot find the file specified." in the log file when I try:

```
Compressing SystemOverview_TrngMan_0103.pptx SystemOverview_TrngMan_0103.docm and Graphics.
The log file is C:\Users\jim\AppData\Local\Temp\ST_SOTG.7z.log.
C:\users\jim\desktop\ST\Training\SystemOverview\working
C:\progra~1\7-zip\7z.exe a ST_SOTG.7z SystemOverview_TrngMan_0103.pptx SystemOverview_TrngMan_0103.docm Graphics
```

When I copy the command as echoed and run it in the command line, 7-Zip creates the archive without any error.

One difference between the first two examples and the one that fails is that $newest has 2 file names, separated by a space. The code that finds the most recent files uses a hash table and $newest is assigned a value with:

```
$newest = $newhash.Values -join ' '
```

I suspect there might be an extra character in the generated command line that 7-Zip does not expect when it parses the command line. I previously had the same error when I put 2 spaces between the file names.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's not possible to run PowerShell v1.0 on Windows 7, as it includes v2.0 out of the box.

Comment: A lot of useful info on running external commands with parameters at this page: http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/.

Comment: Done a quick test using ECHOARGS and your suspucion that the problem relates to the hash table is correct. If I create a simple hashtable with two values and then issue the command `ECHOARGS ($hashtable.values -join ' ')`, then ECHOARGS reports a single parameter consisting the two values separated by a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
    $newest = $newhash.values -join ' '
```

try

```
    $newest = $newhash.values
```

PowerShell will automatically expand an array of values into individual parameters.

Comment: andyb: Thank you. Getting rid of the "-join ' '" worked. With your syntax, is $newest an array?

Comment: Trevor: I assumed (I know that's dangerous) that I am using PS v1.0 because it is in a folder named "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\". But you are correct. According to the $PSVersionTable variable, I am indeed running version 2.0. Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: Good question Jim. I had assumed that it would be an array, but when I tested 'get-member -inputObject $newest', the type name is given as 'System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection'.

Comment: To find type information on PS objects, use `get-member -inputObject $variable'